# Red Sign over drawable folders Android

Tags: android

[image]

what is the Android Development Tools trying to warn me about? and how to fix this?

[image]

I also have app_icon.png on the main drawable folder, but is it not the way of how its done?

Comment: Go to "Window/Show View/Problems" and it should tell you what the problems are

Comment: probably something wrong with namings ... Can you post another image with an expanded folder? Also, `Eclipse -> Problems` should detail about these.

Comment: isn't there anything shown in the Problem-Tab?

Comment: nothing relavant no...

Comment: do you have any plugins that might be causing this?

Comment: Tried to clean your project and/or restart eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a lint warning, something like "you have drawables that are identical in different dpi folders". Change your lint settings, or fix whatever the warning is.

In Eclipse, you can narrow down on the errors/warnings by selecting the folder in question, and setting `Show > Errors/Warnings on Selection`

[image]